# How to detect whether a file exists?

Tags: c#, file, ftp

Can any one suggest to me the best way to see if a file exists? `File.Exists` is not working for me.

```
string abc = "me_label.deploy";
File.Exists(abc)
```

The file, `abc`, is coming from `Streamreader.ReadLine();`.

I even used the full path.  I don't want to include files in my project.  If I include it in my project it is working fine.

My code:

```
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("me@localhost/"; + ab);
//ab=newfolder/newfolder1
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
string abc = sr.ReadLine();
while (abc != null)
{
    result.Append(abc);
    //abc=file
    result.Append("\n");
    if (File.Exists(ab+abc))
    {
        //file
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is file.exists not working for you? Can you step through and see the correct path?

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: `File.Exists is not working for me`. It is a deterministic function. Doesn't work randomly.

Comment: Due to your comment about ftp - Maybe this can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140704/c-sharp-ftpwebrequest-file-version-check .

Answer (score 5):

Any relative path in .NET is by default relative to the `bin/Debug` subdirectory of your project. So, unless `me_label.deploy` is in that folder, your program will not be able to find it. If you include it, it is copied to that folder and then it works.

But you have to make the path absolute instead. Use the methods from the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).

```
string filename = "me_label.deploy";
string basePath = @"C:\My Documents\";
string absolutePath = Path.Combine(basePath, filename);
// C:\My Documents\me_label.deploy
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(absolutePath));
```

Comment: +1. But I would substitute `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` for `basePath`.

Comment: Its working fine if i include it in my project, i want it to download newly, i dont want to add those files to my project. I want it to check from ftp link only.

Comment: @ispiro I agree, but it was just any random path off the top of my head. I don't know where the OP has stored this file.

Comment: FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://me@localhost/" + ab);
//ab=newfolder/newfolder1
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
string abc = sr.ReadLine();
while (abc != null)
{
result.Append(abc);      //abc=file
                result.Append("\n");
                
                if (File.Exists(ab+abc))
                {
                    //file
                    }}

Comment: @user2155670 Please combine `ab` and `abc` using the technique I show.